# Splitting HTML without cutting the tags

Tags: php, html

I've been trying to split a PHP string in an arbitrary number of characters per split. However, I'm looking for a way to do so without breaking HTML tags. Here is an example:

```
$string = 'Section 1: 
<table width = "528" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>    <td width="20"> </td>   <td width="15" valign="top"> &bull; </td>   <td valign="top"> Element 1 </td></tr>
<tr>    <td width="20"> </td>   <td width="15" valign="top"> &bull; </td>   <td valign="top"> Element 2 </td></tr>
<tr>    <td width="20"> </td>   <td width="15" valign="top"> &bull; </td>   <td valign="top"> Element 3 </td></tr>
<tr>    <td width="20"> </td>   <td width="15" valign="top">&bull; </td>    <td valign="top"> Element 4 </td></tr>
<tr>    <td width="20"> </td>   <td width="15" valign="top"> &bull; </td>   <td valign="top"> Element 5 </td></tr>
<tr>    <td width="20"> </td>   <td width="15" valign="top"> &bull; </td>   <td valign="top"> Element 6 </td></tr>
</table>

Section 2:
<table width = "528" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>    <td width="20"> </td>   <td width="15" valign="top"> &bull; </td>   <td valign="top"> Element 7 </td></tr>
<tr>    <td width="20"> </td>   <td width="15" valign="top"> &bull; </td>   <td valign="top"> Element 8 </td></tr>
<tr>    <td width="20"> </td>   <td width="15" valign="top"> &bull; </td>   <td valign="top"> Element 9 </td></tr>
<tr>    <td width="20"> </td>   <td width="15" valign="top"> &bull; </td>   <td valign="top"> Element 10 </td></tr>
<tr>    <td width="20"> </td>   <td width="15" valign="top"> &bull; </td>   <td valign="top"> Element 11 </td></tr>
<tr>    <td width="20"> </td>   <td width="15" valign="top"> &bull; </td>   <td valign="top"> Element 12 </td></tr>
<tr>    <td width="20"> </td>   <td width="15" valign="top"> &bull; </td>   <td valign="top"> Element 13 </td></tr>
</table>';

$charAmount = 450;
$textSplit = array();

while ($string){
    array_push($textSplit, substr($string, 0, $charAmount));
    $string = substr($string, $charAmount);
}

var_dump($textSplit);
```

In this case, two  tags are broken. I'd like whatever tag that is cut up at the end of a split to just skip to the next split, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Have you considered parsing the DOM with something like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: I like the idea, but I am in a situation where I can't really use external files like this :(

Comment: You could split the string on the set of tags with a regexp, then build up your string with the pieces; when you get to where you would go over your character limit, decide whether the next piece is a tag or is splittable, then go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not php guys, But logicwise I can help, just before split check which of dese two character is present nearest backwards from the split index  `<` or `>`

if `<` is encountered u r splitting in wrong place so skip

if `>` is encountered go ahead with split

I have done it in jQuery successfully sometimes back

Answer (score 0):

About Splitting html string, I have no ideas now but cutting string with limit character you could refer the solution at the link: https://github.com/dhngoc/php-cut-html-string.
This resource may help you to get more ideas.